# Odoo - How to set domain filter from backend

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am using odoo 10e. What i want to do is i want to set domain criteria inside `fields_view_get` method

```
    @api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(Customer, self).fields_view_get(
        view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
    if view_type == 'tree':
        if self.env.user.partner_id.parent_id.id is False:
            id = self.env.user.id
        else:
            id = self.env.user.partner_id.parent_id.id
        doc.attrib['domain'] = "[('custodians','='," + str(id) + ")]"

    for node_form in doc.xpath("//tree"):
        node_form.attrib['duplicate'] = '0'
        res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    for node_form in doc.xpath("//form"):
        node_form.attrib['duplicate'] = '0'
        res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res
```

this is what i did tried. But its not working. You can see why i want to set domain from backend because i have to set user_id based on condition.

Please let me know if i am doing wrong or is there any better way.

**Edit**

I have defined custodians fields as follow

```
custodians = fields.Many2one('res.users', string="Custodian", domain=[('groups_id', 'in', [12])],
                             readonly=[('readonly_custodian', '=', True)])
```

actually when ever a loggedin user create a `Customer` records we set him as a custodian for that `Customer` and all i want to do is when that user loggin again he should be able to see his and his parent custodian records

Comment: You should rarely need to override `fields_get`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to add domain filter on tree view, dynamically from back-end. So that i can have condition based domain filter

Comment: see everything under this check `if view_type == 'tree'`. This is the condition i want to achieve in domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you should be able to achieve this behavior by modifying the `domain` on the [action](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/actions.html) that loads your tree view.

There are two ways that [Window Actions](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/actions.html#window-actions-ir-actions-act-window) might be defined, but either way, the important part is the `domain` value.

**Old answer:**

First way:

```
<act_window id="..."
            name="..."
            ...
            domain="[('custodians','=',user.partner_id.parent_id and user.partner_id.parent_id.id or user.id)]"/>
```

Second way:

```
<record id="..." model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="domain">[('custodians','=',user.partner_id.parent_id and user.partner_id.parent_id.id or user.id)]</field>
</record>
```

---

**EDIT:**

Since it seems `user` is not accessible in the `domain`, I think this might work:

**[Record Rule](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/security.html#record-rules)**

```
<record id="view_ir_rule_restrict_custodians" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Restrict Users to see only their Custodians</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_res_partner"/>
    <!-- Should this be `... or user.partner_id.id`? -->
    <field name="domain_force">[('custodians','=',user.partner_id.parent_id and user.partner_id.parent_id.id or user.id)]</field>
</record>
```

*Note: This is a global rule, so you may want to forcefully remove it for some groups (like managers)*

```
<record id="view_ir_rule_unrestrict_custodians_managers" model="ir.rule">
    <field name="name">Un-Restrict Managers to see any Custodians</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_res_partner"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[(1, '=', 1)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_sale_manager'))]"/>
</record>
```

**EDIT 2:**

As we found in chat, the domain specific to your question is this:

```
[('custodians','in',user.partner_id.parent_id and [(user.partner_id.parent_id.id),user.partner_id.id] or [user.partner_id.id])]
```

Comment: well i think `user` is not available in domain .. let me double check it

Comment: Yes, as i said user object is not available, see i got this error `Uncaught Error: NameError: name 'user' is not defined`

Comment: @Ancient Can you try it as `uid` instead of `user`? I think it is just an integer, not an object, so you will probably still have an error. If you can use a simple `[('custodians','=',uid)]` then you should be able to go a different route. Let me know if it works either way with `uid` and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes, i tried it before `[('custodians','=',uid)]` it works. What the different route ?

Comment: but `uid` is current loggedin user id not the id i want

Comment: @Ancient Are you open to using a [Record Rule](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/security.html#record-rules) to determine who should be able to see what records? Or do you need it just for this particular case? Can you update your question with the definition of the `custodians` field?

Comment: I am open to resolve this issue, don't care what is the way to resolve this. Also please check `custodians` definition in question is updated

Comment: @Ancient Updated answer with record rules solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156690/discussion-between-ancient-and-travisw).